# Accept rate- What to do if nobody answers your question, and you don't know the answer

Tags: discussion, accept-rate, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poor answers and accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40735/poor-answers-and-accept-rate)

I have a couple of questions which I've asked, which never got an answer worthy of acceptance. I still don't know the answer to them either, so I don't want to just answer it saying "I don't know" but I also don't want my accept rate to go down. I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you might want to try to [get attention for your unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: Thanks everyone. Guess I was looking too much into the whole accepted rate thing.

Comment: Thanks Phillip for trying, however, that's always important. Being concerned is much better and speaks much more highly of you than "meh"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you'd still benefit from a solution to the problem, just leave the questions open and **don't worry about your accept rate**. You currently have a accept rate of 88%. That's more than enough. Anything above 70% is actually considered [excellent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16639).

If you still *need* a solution, consider placing a small [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to your question.

If you don't need a solution any more (the problem fixed itself, etc.) and you think nobody else will ever encounter the same problem, you *can* delete your question. But doing this *only* to improve your accept rate is wrong (it's just a meaningless statistic).

Moreover, bulk-deleting question might you get question banned, so reserve deletion for truly obsolete questions.