# Visual threshold for good accept rates

Tags: feature-request, design, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce the percentage at which an accept-rate is coloured green](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135266/reduce-the-percentage-at-which-an-accept-rate-is-coloured-green)

I was just [referred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144362/poor-answers-shouldnt-count-towards-the-accept-rate#comment411359_144369) to an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/168610) regarding the accept rate:

> In general, an accept rate of **70% or better is quite good**, meaning you
>   accept answers on 7 out of 10 questions that you ask.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

However, the display of the accept rates indicates that rates up to 80% are "not so great" by colouring them in a grey shade, while rates above 80% are green, which presumably indicates "good".

In accordance to the *accepted answer to an faq question*, this threshold should be lowered to 70% (inclusively).

<sub>Either that or that answer should be edited.</sub>

Comment: [Let's just get rid of the damn thing already.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Comment: @Bart: Well, that's a separate discussion. **If** we keep it, it should match the faq. **If** we keep it, it should be decent.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks, that's well argued (better than this question). It appears the single answer nailed it.