# Allow user to post a "best solution" from parsing responses to questions

Tags: feature-request

Would it be of benefit to allow someone to post a 'best solution' to a question?  I have seen many, many situations where people respond with answers to a question with conflicting details.  These conflicting answers both receive up-votes.

This leaves me wondering which answer is correct?  Are they both correct?  Neither? I realize the up-vote and Accept Answer is intended to point to a response as the correct answer, but as the person granting the Accepted Answer probably didn't know as much about the subject as the people answering the question is the person posting the question in a position to really know which answer(s) is/are right?

I guess what I'm driving at is that maybe a new sub/super type of answer should be allowed where a more authoritative and complete response could be posted.  Something above and beyond 'Accepted Answer'.

Comment: High votes on answers which aren't accepted pretty much covers this already. The community says they like this answer better, even though the OP says this one solved it for them.

Comment: The answer that is correct is the one that works for you.

Comment: it makes me sad that i can't down vote my own post.  i think my post has more to do with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted) than other issues.

Answer (score 4):

High votes on answers which aren't accepted pretty much covers this already. The community says they like this answer better, even though the OP says this one solved it for them.

If none of them quite cut it still add another answer that merges/corrects them, possibly making it CW or edit the others if they're CW or the changes aren't too major.

You can also use bounties if you think the question is important and deserves a canonical answer that rocks.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be of benefit to allow someone to post a 'best solution' to a question?

Allow? If someone wishes to post such an answer, they are free to do so. No one is stopping it.

> maybe a new sub/super type of answer should be allowed where a more authoritative and complete response could be posted. Something above and beyond 'Accepted Answer'.

And how would this be determined? Who will issue this "Complete Response"?