# Accepted answer should not be first if there is a more highly upvoted answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Its ordered by the number of votes but the answer chosen by the user is shown first. In some of the questions, the chosen one may not be right or incomplete or not so good as a different one. Many new users may not scroll for the second one which might have more votes. The actual owner may not come back and select the new better answer. I think a good option would be to display the highly voted answer first, followed by the chosen answer and then the rest in the order of the votes. This way good answers are not missed.

In short,
When the answers are sorted by votes, my suggestion is to put the chosen answer(by the owner of the question) in the *second* place than the first place.

Comment: There's already a tab that says "Votes" above the answers that sorts it by vote count.

Comment: I know that. But that puts the chosen one in the top, my suggestion is to put that in the second place

Comment: I totally agree with this request. From the dupe linked above it seems this has been implemented in 2009, but changed since?

Comment: Even if the order is not changed, at least a note indicating that there are better answers down would help. Like this question suggests but downvoted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112918/change-answer-order-slightly

Answer (score 0):

No please. The current order is perfect. If the accepted answer is not good then it can be downvoted so new user can also understand that the answer is not appropriate. So he/she will definitely look at the second (most voted) answer.

Comment: If it is wrong, yes, it can be downvoted. But if it just not so great as the one voted high by the community, no one will bother downvoting the correct but not good enough answer

Comment: What message are we sending to new users if the accepted answer is heavily downvoted, but still shown on top?

Comment: "Perfect" is a very strong word to describe anything on the Internet, and maybe especially community-driven sites like SO :-).