# I found answers for a question not really correct, what I should do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The offending question is [How to get current route in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2)

<s>Every</s> Some answer suggests the use of `_route` and it works in most cases, really - I personally also use that solution.

Until I found that it isn't work in one case (if the request is forwarded from another controller, `_route` is null). I do a google and I find something worse.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/854

As fabpot (Symfony developer) said

> You should never rely on the _route. It's only available for debugging purpose.

And I am puzzled of what I should do in this case. I only have 30 rep and cannot comment and such...

And I **don't** know the "correct" way of solving the question itself.

---

So I re-read all the answers. Indeed there are better answers that avoid `request.attributes.get('_route')` (which I think what fabpot in that github issue talks about) and are (officially) documented in some way.

I don't upvote those because I would like to check myself before doing so, but I don't have Symfony nearby at the moment.

At the moment, it seems that I could treat this case as incorrect answer(s), and I could just go check [FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/what-is-the-etiquette-for-correcting-old-questions-with-incorrect-answers) for that.

Anyway, at least I know what to do now :) About the rep thing, it just takes time. lol.

Comment: No, you don't flag incorrect answers. You downvote them.

Comment: I cannot downvote! Did I mention I don't have enough reputation?

Comment: Then you need to earn enough rep so that you can.

Comment: you should also write your own answer to the question.  If it is correct, then it will get some upvotes, at which time you'll earn enough rep to then comment on the others

Comment: @luiges90 "`fabpot symfony dev said`" he's the creator and Lead Dev of Symfony - a fairly authoritative source :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to go about it is to downvote the answer & optionally mention the reason for the downvote.

Since you don't have enough reputation to comment or downvote, you can

- Try posting an answer on a question that's not been answered/ hasn't received much attention
- Have a look at some questions on the [homepage](http://stackoverflow.com) & see if you can edit some questions/answers and fix them. Each suggested edit, when approved gives you +2 rep (to a limit of 1,000) & you can earn some rep this way, enough to drop a comment.

Comment: He can't downvote either, it's a 125 privilege.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha never claimed he can, just mentioned what the expection of a wrong answer is.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are 2 general ways to go about this:

1. Get some reputation. Commenting requires 50 rep. Downvoting requires 125. I had both of these privileges on my first day. Not that difficult. Ask, answer, suggest to edit.
2. Bring the question to the community's awareness by

   1. Posting it here on meta with a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag.
   2. Going to chat with it (talking requires 20 reputation, which you have), and discussing it there.

Good luck!